# Using href and routerLink with Angular 4?

Tags: angular, seo

I'm running a personal website/blog built on Angular 4. A problem I'm running into with SEO is that I can specify the main URLs in the sitemap, e.g. /home, /blog, /contact, and Google is crawling and rendering them fine. I'm not using Universal by the way.

The problem I'm running into is that the crawler doesn't seem to be following the links not in the sitemap. E.g. blog post urls, /blog/blog-post-1. Generating a dynamic sitemap to include all of the blog posts would be possible but more effort than it's worth.

Does anyone have ideas on how to get crawlers to crawl these links?

Comment: have you got any solution to this?

Comment: @amansoni211 I've tried various things and nothing worked. So I ended up hosting the site with Universal and used a sitemap generator.